# Divide and Conquer Hull Algorithm

Tags: java

Hello my question today is to breakdown and figure out how to actually code the LOWER TANGENT part of the algorithm Ive managed to complete steps (1) and (2) but I am now on stuck on step (3).

Divide and Conquer Convex Hull

Hull(S) :

(1) If |S| <= 3, then compute the convex hull by brute force in O(1)
time and return.

(2) Otherwise, partition the point set S into two sets A and B, where
A consists of half the points with the lowest x coordinates and B
consists of half of the points with the highest x coordinates.

(3) Recursively compute HA = Hull(A) and HB = Hull(B).

(4) Merge the two hulls into a common convex hull, H, by computing the
upper and lower tangents for HA and HB and discarding all the points
lying between these two tangents.

http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~pless/506/l3_1.gif

**Finding the Lower Tangent**

LowerTangent(HA ; HB ) :

(1) Let a be the rightmost point of HA .

(2) Let b be the leftmost point of HB .

(3) While ab is not a lower tangent for HA and HB do

(a) While ab is not a lower tangent to HA do a = a - 1 (move a clockwise).

(b) While ab is not a lower tangent to HB do b = b + 1 (move b counterclockwise).

(4) Return ab.

Quoted from: http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~pless/506/l3.html
This explanation is the best that describe my problem.

The functions for Lexisort and convexHull have not been included as they are working, the DC hull algorithm has been included to provide context.

My current code:

```
public static int [][] dcHull(int [][]merged){

    if(merged.length <= 3)
        return convexHull(merged);

    else {

        lexiSort(merged);
        //split(P, A, B);
        //SPLIT
        double p = merged.length;
        int A;
        int B;

        if (p%2 == 0){//EVEN
            A = (int) (p/2);
            B = (int) (p/2);
        }
        else//ODD
            A = (int) (1+(p/2));
            B = (int) (p/2);



        int arrayA[][] = new int[A][2]; 
        int arrayB[][] = new int[B][2];

        for (int i=0; i<A; i++){
            arrayA[i][0] = merged[i][0];
            arrayA[i][1] = merged[i][1];
        }

        for (int i=0; i<B; i++){
            arrayB[i][0] = merged[i+A][0];
            arrayB[i][1] = merged[i+A][1];
        }

        for ( int i=0; i<arrayA.length; i++){
            System.out.println( "Merged array A Coordinates: " + arrayA[i][0] +", " + arrayA[i][1]);}
        for ( int i=0; i<arrayB.length; i++){
            System.out.println( "Merged array B Coordinates: " + arrayB[i][0] +", " + arrayB[i][1]);}

        lowerT(arrayA, arrayB);
        //upperT(arrayA, arrayB);


        return merged(dcHull(convexHull(arrayA)), dcHull(convexHull(arrayB)));

    }

}

public static int[][] lowerT(int [][] hulla, int [][]  hullb){

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    //LOWER TANGENT
    //(1) Let a be the rightmost point of HA .
    for (int i=0; i<hulla.length; i++){
        if (a < hulla[i][0]){
            a = hulla[i][0];
        }
    }
    //(2) Let b be the leftmost point of HB .
    for (int i=0; i<hullb.length; i++){
        if (b < hullb[i][0]){
            b = hullb[i][0];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<hullb.length; i++){
        if (b > hullb[i][0]){
            b = hullb[i][0];
        }
    }
```

The code finishes after working out a of HA and b of HB however I do not understand (3) or more precisely how to code it using the elements I have.

(1) Let a be the rightmost point of HA .

(2) Let b be the leftmost point of HB .

There is an additional method of code called right turn that I believe is useful:
"Lower tangency is a condition that can be
tested locally by an orientation test of the two vertices and
neighboring vertices on the hull."

Im just not sure how to put it together.

```
public static boolean rightTurn(int [][] rt, int counter) //AxBxC = (Bx-Ax)(Cy-Ay)-(By-Ay)(Cx-Ax)
{
    int ax = rt[counter-2][0];
    int bx = rt[counter-1][0];
    int cx = rt[counter][0];

    int ay = rt[counter-2][1];
    int by = rt[counter-1][1];
    int cy = rt[counter-0][1];
    int result =(bx-ax)*(cy-ay)-(by-ay)*(cx-ax);

    if (result < 0){                            // Result = VE+ (Right Turn), 0, VE- (Left Turn)

        return true;                                                    //VE- = TRUE = Right Turn
    }

    else return false;                                                  //VE+ = FALSE = Left Turn
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of work that someone has to read and understand.  Any chance you can pair it down a bit to make it easier to provide some help?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier Im not used to this system yet. Sure I'll format my questions more explicitly in future. =)

Answer (score 5):

First,

```
//(2) Let b be the leftmost point of HB .
for (int i=0; i<hullb.length; i++){
    if (b < hullb[i][0]){
        b = hullb[i][0];
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<hullb.length; i++){
    if (b > hullb[i][0]){
        b = hullb[i][0];
    }
}
```

there seems to be a leftover copy-pasto.

Now, let us try to change "however I do not understand (3) or more precisely how to code it using the elements I have".

> (a) While ab is not a lower tangent to HA do a = a - 1 (move a clockwise).

So you need a test whether a straight line is a lower tangent to HA. The geometrical situation here simplfies the test. Fundamental is of course the convexity of HA. The considered straight lines,*L*, always pass through a vertex of HA, say *v*, and a vertwx of HB, say *b*. Let the two neighbouring vertices be *u* and *w*, labelled so that *u, v, w* is a clockwise piece of the boundary. There are three possibilities, 1. *u* and *w* both lie above or on *L*, then, by convexity, *L* is a lower tangent to HA; 2. one of *u* and *w* lies above or on *L*, the other below; 3. both lie below *L*.

*w* lies below *L* if and only if the path *bvw* makes a left turn at *v*.
*u* lies below *L* if and only if the path *bvu* makes a left turn at *v*.

You need a function to check whether a path *ABC* makes a left turn (by an angle less than 180°) at *B*. Your `rightTurn` has the gist, but the wrong parameters, because one of the points you want to test belongs to the other hull. And test that you got the signs right, it's easy to slip there.

So while either of the two neighbours of *v* lies below the straight line through *b* and *v*, replace *v* by its clockwise neighbour and check again. Take care of the array bounds when picking neighbours.

After a couple of steps you've found a straight line which is a lower tangent to HA, but in general not of HB.

> (b) While ab is not a lower tangent to HB do b = b + 1 (move b counterclockwise).

This is analogous, but with a change of orientation. A point *p* on the boundary of HB lies below the straight line through *a* (a vertex of HA) and *b* (the considered vertex of HB) if and only if the path *pba* makes a left turn at *b*.

Picking counterclockwise neighbours on the boundary of HB until a lower tangent of HB is found rotates the line about the vertex *a* on the boundary of HA, so that that lower tangent of HB need not be a lower tangent of HA anymore (look at the picture you linked).

So back to 3 (a). That will rotate the line about *b*, possibly so much that it is no longer a lower tangent to HB. 3 (b) again.
Iterate until you found a lower tangent to both.

```
aIndex = findRightmostA();
bIndex = findLeftmostB();
while(!(lowerTangentA (aIndex, bIndex) && lowerTangentB(aIndex, bIndex))){
    aIndex = findLowerTangentA(aIndex, bIndex);
    bIndex = findLowerTangentB(aIndex, bIndex);
}

lowerTangentA(aIndex, bIndex){
    ux = hulla[aIndex+1][0];
    uy = hulla[aIndex+1][1]; // array bounds!
    ax = hulla[aIndex][0];
    ay = hulla[aIndex][1];
    wx = hulla[aIndex-1][0];
    wy = hulla[aIndex-1][1];
    bx = hullb[bIndex][0];
    by = hullb[bIndex][1];
    return !(leftTurn(bx,by,ax,ay,ux,uy) || leftTurn(bx,by,ax,ay,wx,wy));
}
```

Finding the upper tangent to both hulls is analogous. It is worthwhile to try and abstract the tangent checks so that you can use the same function for all checks (lower/upper, HA/HB).